# Can we get prettier code markup?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

It looks like all we have is preformatted text

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    ....
}
```

Could we get prettier markup? maybe C++ syntax highlighting would be decent enough?

We'll surely have quite a bit of shader code (GLSL and HLSL), but probably lots of C++ and some other languages as well.

Comment: It [doesn't appear](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/prettify.js) Prettify has [HG]LSL support (which is [what StackOverflow uses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019)). A pull request might be in order! As for highlighting on here, that's probably staffer thing.

Comment: did this only get fixed in the meta? my posts in the main one don't have the better highlighting.

Comment: @AlanWolfe do your questions work on main now? If not could you link to an example?

Comment: Doesn't seem to:
http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/4/is-a-cubic-lagrange-interpolation-tensor-product-the-same-as-bicubic-interpolati

Comment: I've edited that question to have C++ syntax highlighting and it shows up now (at least in the preview - it should show up once someone accepts the edit). Unlike on Stack Overflow it doesn't have a language tag to trigger this automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure what makes it work automatically in this meta question. Does the use of "C++" in the question wording affect it?