# Is anyone interested in adding GLSL and HLSL to our syntax highlighting?

Tags: discussion

Following the meta post [Can we get prettier code markup?](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/can-we-get-prettier-code-markup) syntax highlighting has been activated for our site. For example, if you want the code in your post to show up with C++ syntax highlighting, you simply include the following in your post:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-cplusplus -->
```

If you only want it to apply to the next code block (if you have more than one code block and want to use more than one language), just omit the `-all`:

```
<!-- language: lang-cplusplus -->
```

---

**This works for a wide range of languages, but not all, and notably not GLSL or HLSL, which are likely to be in frequent use on our site.**

Looking at the language extension files for [prettify.js](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) (which Stack Exchange uses for syntax highlighting), most seem to be between 30 and 100 lines of code including extensive commenting, so writing one for GLSL or HLSL seems like it would be a reasonable task for someone familiar with the languages.

Would anyone be interested in doing this?

If so, indicating here will allow collaboration if we have more than one person interested, and we can link to work in progress.

Comment: Currently I don't have the time to do that, but after having a quick look into the files it looks a bit similar to the GeSHi config files. And GeSHi already has GLSL support, so the [GeSHi GLSL config file (on GitHub)](https://github.com/GeSHi/geshi-1.0/blob/master/src/geshi/glsl.php) could maybe help when addressing this.

Comment: I also have a [GeSHi syntax file for HLSL](https://gist.github.com/Reedbeta/1abfc4b878d78a5813ea) (originally by [Nick Darnell](http://www.nickdarnell.com/), though it's apparently not on his site anymore).

Comment: Well, in the mean time, C/C++ highlighting should do the job. It should only miss the `vec3`s/`float3`s...

Comment: I've added answers for voting on different languages so anyone considering writing an extension can see which languages are most in demand here.

Comment: I've since discovered that simply providing a list of options to vote on is [not the best way to have a discussion](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/106/polling-questions-good-or-bad). Feel free to add answers that express opinions rather than simply giving options.

Answer (score 12):

## Upvotes indicate demand for GLSL syntax highlighting

Feel free to edit in any reasons / examples.

Example questions and answers:

- [Why is accessing textures much slower when calculating the texture coordinate in the fragment shader?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/266/why-is-accessing-textures-much-slower-when-calculating-the-texture-coordinate-in)
- [How to reduce the number of draw calls when rendering one object multiple times?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/271/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-draw-calls-when-rendering-one-object-multiple-times)

Answer (score 11):

## Upvotes indicate demand for HLSL syntax highlighting

Feel free to edit in any reasons / examples.

Answer (score 2):

## Upvotes indicate demand for OpenCL syntax highlighting

Feel free to edit in any reasons / examples.

Answer (score 2):

## Upvotes indicate demand for CUDA syntax highlighting

Feel free to edit in any reasons / examples.